# Report Filter: Parent Case Number behaving oddly

Tags: reporting, filters, parent

This seems like it should be simple but I'm stuck - I don't know Salesforce very well so hoping someone here can help.  I have a set of parent cases, and each of those has a number of child cases.  All of these cases are of the same type, "PV".  I want to do a report of all the open parent cases.  I started with three criteria:

```
    Closed equals "False"
AND Type contains "PV"
AND Parent Case Number equals 0
```

This query finds no records.  If I change the third line to

```
AND Parent Case Number not equal to 0
```

the report successfully finds all the child cases.

So, I tried adding "filter logic":

```
(1 AND 2 AND (NOT 3))
```

and I'm back to getting no data.

I feel like I must be missing something super obvious, grateful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

So, some additional google sleuthing led me to an article on Salesforce's site regarding Parent Case Number: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000320527&type=1

Apparently, the correct answer is to use

```
Parent Case Number less or equal "0"
```

Kinda ridiculous that "parent case number" shows up on the report as a zero, but its internal value is apparently less than zero.